# data is not stored in database with hibernate and spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to add element in database and when I run nothing is stored, I'm using hibernate and  spring for devlopping a web applicaion with mavan. and I had not any error but nothing is stored
applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="datasource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_bp"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="GESTION_BP"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="com.sqli.bap.daoImpl.PersonneDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="metier" class="com.sqli.bap.metierImpl.PersonneMetierImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

The hibernate.xml file

```
    <persistence-unit name="GESTION_BP"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And these is my dao class

```
public class PersonneDaoImpl implements IPersonneDao {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public void ajouterPersonne(Personne personne) {
    //em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(personne);
    //em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? Does it freeze? I can't help you if you don't give me more infos...

Comment: I don't have any error everything sames works correctly but nothing is stored in the database

Comment: Since you have `hibernate.show_sql` to true, does the generated SQL seems correct?

Comment: No nothing is genereted in my console

Comment: Are you sure that `ajouterPersonne` is called? (Maybe add an output debug). Are you sure personne is not null? (Don't remember if it raises an exception)

Comment: I added a try catch bloc and I have java.lang.NullPointerException but when I use personne.getAdresse or getNom I can see data in it

Comment: Has your persistence context been initialized? (`em == null` maybe?)

Comment: I have now these execption Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'persistenceUnitManager' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]: Bean property 'persistenceUnitManager' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: I may have found your error : the EntityManager field is private, so the Bean manager can't modify it.

Comment: I changed to public but the same problem

Comment: Someone to help please

Comment: If I understand correctly the exception description `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` contains `setPersistenceUnitManager` but no getter associated. The bean cannot be created because of that. Can't help you better I'm afraid.

Comment: What did you change to start getting the BeanCreationException.  You shouldn't need a getter and the XML you have seems ok.

Comment: @user0321, Post complete stacktrace of exception to your question, don't add it as part of comments to your post. Also when you started getting this error, you have done any changes?

Comment: Did you mapped your entity class for Personne. Add the mapping if not already.